# Selector for all elements that appear after an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am aware of the `+` selector that allows us to manipulate an adjacent element, but I'm looking to manipulate all of the elements rather than just one.

```
<article class="non-selected"></article>
<nav id="nav-below"></nav>
<article class="select-me"></article>
<article class="select-me"></article>
<article class="select-me"></article>
<footer class="dont-select-me"></footer>
```

In the example above I'm trying to select each of the `article`'s with the `select-me` class. (I can't use a normal class selector).

Is this possible for jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators):

```
.non-selected ~ .select-me {
    color: red;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XFGfd/5/

Comment: Amazing! Knew there would be a way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `~` instead of  `+`, all following elements will be matched

For exemple,

```
article.non-selected ~ article.select-me{} /*  will select all articles having .select-me class that are siblings but after a article having the .non-selected element class */
```

Using jQuery

```
$('article.non-selected ~ article.select-me')....
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery:** [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/OGenehI/1/edit)

```
$('#nav-below').nextUntil('.dont-select-me')  // do something
```

<sub>http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/</sub>

**Or using CSS *[General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)* (~): [LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OGenehI/2/edit)**

```
#nav-below ~ article{ 
  background:red; 
}
```